# rails application connect to a mongoid replicaset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, database-replication

I'm having difficulty connecting to a mongoid replicaset from a rails app.

I have the following config:

```
dev1:
  clients:
    default:
      database: opera_bounties_dev1
      hosts:
        - 10.0.0.1:27017
        - 10.0.0.2:27017
#      read: :secondary
#      slave_ok: true
      options:
#        read: :secondary
        replicaSet: operaeventrsX
        consistency: :strong
        pool_size: 200
#        slave_ok: true
#        connect: :replica_set
```

I can connect to the primary just fine, but if I shut down the primary, I cannot connect to the secondary. Now if I connect via mongo shell to the secondary and issue `rs.slaveOk()`, I can connect to the secondary for that one session. I need my rails app to connect to mongo with slaveOk always. setting `slave_ok: true` in the configuration (above) doesn't do it... What is the trick here?

Answer (score 2):

The working config is:

```
dev1:
  clients:
    default:
      database: dbname_dev1
      hosts:
        - 10.0.0.1:27017
        - 10.0.0.2:27017
      options:
        read: 
          mode: :secondary_preferred
        consistency: :strong
        pool_size: 200
        connect: :replica_set
        replica_set: replicaSetName
```